# Failed to start Asp.net Development Server while Debuging 2.0 Website in VS 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a 2.0 website (Not web App) which i am trying to debug in VS 2012.

The error i get is

```
Failed to start Asp.Net Development Server on port : 4599
Error: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

I tried netstat-o and and port 4599 is unused.

Tried opening VS2012 in Admin mode, still no luck.

The app is runing fine when hosted in IIS in the same machine (Win 7). Only it will not run in VS.

Tried another 2.0 website, still same error.

What is causing this ?

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm...Have you tried disabling any firewall that might be running?

Comment: @Nikki9696  you are spot on. its my Antivirus !!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, this port is bound to a specific host name, therefore starting a socket on the same port as asp.net development server does (any host name) is not allowed

Check your IIS web site bindings

Or Switch to another port on IIS

Comment: I have a default website and binding shows only port 80

Comment: Then after fixing the antivirus you can change it to 4599 and bind it to a specific host name and then my answer becomes valid :) sorry..

Comment: but it does not have any port specified in IIs. besides i am not hosting in IIS i just want to debug it in VS2012. So how will it help? can you explain?

Comment: I was just trying to be funny :o you solved your issue right? It was the antivirus?